# Uploading a jar into Archiva repository using maven

Tags: maven, jar, pom.xml

I am trying to deploy a jar (javax.mail jar) in apache-archiva internal repository using maven. I know we can do this easily manually but I wanted to try it using maven. My Pom.xml is as follows :

*http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.tripod.demo
    Karthik-project
    war
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    Karthik-project Maven Webapp

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.Final</version>
            <configuration>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.5</version>
                <filename>/home/smadugula/mail-1.4.5.jar</filename>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>archiva.internal</id>
        <name>Internal Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/archiva/repository/internal</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>archiva.snapshots</id>
        <name>Internal Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/archiva/repository/snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

*

and I am using this to execute it :

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=/home/smadugula/mail-1.4.5.jar \
                       -DrepositoryId= \
                       -Dfile=/home/smadugula/Karthik-project/target/Karthik-project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar \
                       -DpomFile=/MavenWorkspace/Karthik-project/pom.xml \
```

But the problem is, when I do this I keep getting an error like :

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project Karthik-project: /home/smadugula/Karthik-project/target/Karthik-project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar not found.
```

I have changed the settings.xml file but I can't figure out how to edit the pom. Can anyone help me how to I configure my pom so as to do this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you configure to let archiva work like a proxy between you and maven central? If yes you only need to define the artifact as a dependency and will automatically downloaded via Maven into archiva.

Comment: I already did that in settings.xml file and added the javax.mail in the dependency but it didn't work.